# Turning H1 Heading Into 3 Separate Lines Instead of 2

Tags: html, css

Newbie here, I'm trying to figure out how to do this:
[3 Lined H1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIw3X.png)

Right now, I have this:
[2 Lined H1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhHUb.jpg)

I know that I could probably achieve this by doing 3 H1's in HTML

```
<h1> Learn How To Build An </h1>
<h1> EPIC </h1>
<h1> Battlestation Setup </h1>
```

But the problem with that is that now there are 3 H1's which isn't good for SEO.

Right now the code I have to achieve the 2 lines is:

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="hero">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-col-cta">
            <p class="subheading">Whether You Need It For Work Or Gaming...</p>

            <h1>Learn How To Build An <span>EPIC</span> Battlestation Setup</h1>

            <a href="#" class="main-hero-cta">Buying Guides</a>
            <a href="#" class="secondary-hero-cta">Info Guides</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url("../Images/Hero/hero-background.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

    .left-col-cta {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: white;

        .subheading {
            color: rgb(158, 158, 158);
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2.5em;
            padding: 0 100px;
        }

    }
```

I do have a span there for the 'EPIC' but I don't know what I would need to Google to achieve the result.

How would I go about putting the 'EPIC' in the center and then the 'Battlestation Setup' underneath it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option for this:
Instead of span, put a br(new line) and center each line of text.

```
<div class="hero">
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-col-cta">
        <p class="subheading">Whether You Need It For Work Or Gaming...</p>

        <h1>Learn How To Build An <br/>EPIC<br/> Battlestation Setup</h1>

        <a href="#" class="main-hero-cta">Buying Guides</a>
        <a href="#" class="secondary-hero-cta">Info Guides</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was trying to figure out what the attribute was, worked like a charm! Thank you :)